# Manipulate the setter to avoid null

Tags: c#, .net, properties

usually we have the:

```
public string code { get; set; }
```

I need to avoid null reference exception if eventually someone sets code to null

I try this idea ... any help?

```
public string code { get { } set { if (code == null) { code = default(string); }}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to declare a backing field, which I’ll call `_code` here:

```
private string _code = "";
public string Code
{
    get
    {
        return _code;
    } 
    set 
    { 
        if (value == null) 
            _code = "";
        else
            _code = value;
    }
}
```

I’ve also renamed the property to `Code` because it is customary in C# to capitalise everything that’s public.

Note that in your own code, you wrote `default(string)`, but this is the same as `null`.

Instead of setting `_code` to `""`, it is common practice to throw an exception:

```
private string _code = "";
public string Code
{
    get
    {
        return _code;
    } 
    set 
    { 
        if (value == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        _code = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also like `set { _code = value ?? ""; } ` which is the equivalent of the setter in your first code sample.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
  private string _code="";


public string Code
{
    get
    {  return _code ; } 

    set 
    {
       _code = value ?? "";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incomplete.  You have to define the backing variable if you are using one.  `private string _code = "";`

Comment: closer.  The "P" must be lower case.  C# is case sensitive.

Comment: I pasted this code into Visual Studio which highlighted the fact that it is also missing a ";" after `return _code`

Comment: exactly
for tht i was waiting.
now there is no issues i bet .