# Looking for Generic Method to Assign a Value to an Object Property when the Value being assigned is not null

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

When assigning a value to a new object, if the value being assigned is null need to skip the assignment of this value.

Example of Code

```
class Foo
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public DateTime OpenDate {get; set;}
}

var bar = newFoo();  //bar will not be null at this point

if (newID != null)
   bar.ID = newID;
if (newName != null)
   bar.Name = newName
if (newOpenDate != null)
   bar.OpenDate = newOpenDate;
```

newFoo() sets defaults for the object
the third parties provide new variables, have to work with what is provided, and are not able to change
!= null is a larger method that does multiple checks to see if the value is Empty Space, White Space, Invaid Dates, or different types of null values depending on what source provides newVariable.

What I am hoping for is something similar to this.

```
var bar = newFoo();

Method<Foo>(bar.ID, newID)
Method<Foo>(bar.Name, newName)
Method<Foo>(bar.OpenDate, newOpenDate)
```

EDIT:
The newVariable come from almost 15 different 3rd parties.

So there are 15 different methods to set the values from 3rd party to the new Foo class

Each of the internal classes can have between 10 to 100 properties that could have data that needs to be assigned, depending on which 3rd party is providing the data.

Looking for a better way to assign value to an object's property instead of an if() statement, then assigning for each property.

If the if() statement is the best solution, so be it, just seems like we should be to pass in the object and property and value to be assigned and then assign if needed.

Comment: Why do you need a generic, static method for this when you can just use the setter methods themselves?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manipulate the setter to avoid null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095785/manipulate-the-setter-to-avoid-null)

Comment: @Narish boring :) OP is looking for some cool extension with `ref` and some magical undescribed functionality that somehow pulls in information from a class to do some sort of verification... We need to allow fun back to SO instead of suggesting useful info to OP. :) (On a serious note OP needs to [edit] post to clarify why common approaches like having that code in setters is not working for them)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov haha trust me, I enjoy generics and probably use them in more places then I should, but I am fearful to teach a potential beginner (not to make any presumption about OP's abilities) to use generics like a magic wand. If I was working on something and saw `SetPropertyOnObject<IDontBelongHere?<int, string>>(1, "yes");` I would be very upset

Comment: In your real use case, where are the values coming from? It's likely there's a better solution for your problem than the one you're asking for.